# Hanzi Underline Rules?

Tags: characters

Hanzi has some underlining when dealing with foreign names, etc.

- What are the rules regarding Hanzi underlining?

edit: Would I underline 中国 in a text that includes underlining?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page and it's Chinese version might help: [Proper name mark - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_name_mark)

By the way, we do not use underline as a punctuation in modern simplified Chinese writing. But in a passage (maybe classical Chinese texts) where underline is used, 中国 should be underlined according to the rules.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is taught in Hong Kong and Taiwan, but rarely used in mainland China currently. During the early days of the Republic of China (ROC), a new set of punctuations was introduced in writing and printing. The traditional Chinese is written vertically and a straight line is drawn on the left side of proper noun. For those names of books, a wavy line is drawn instead.  For horizontal writing, a line is drawn under a proper noun. Its function is similar to the capitalisation of proper nouns in English.