# Name underlining (whole word or just part of it?)

Tags: writing

This one **[question](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/hanzi-underline-rules)** is similar, but doesn't quite answer what I am asking here.

If I have a name + title (as in 张老师) how would the underlining work? Would I have to underline the whole word ("**张老师**") or just the name part ("**张**"老师)?

What about compound words (like 中国画)?
I have a feeling that underlining compound words (even only the name) would make the text loaded of underlining info ("**中国**"画、"**汉**"语、"**越**"剧、"**中**"餐、"**英**"文、etc).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: And I would think that name underlining has become obsolete already.

Comment: It may has, but for a student's book I think it could help a lot, at least at basic and intermediate levels.

Answer (score 1):

For compound words, the whole word is the proper noun and should be marked as a whole.

Text full of underlining is proper but may look crowded, in which case there are typographical optimizations you can apply, such as increased line height and character padding, or use bold instead of underlining for the markup.

Answer (score 1):

First we use your example “张老师”.  It's ok and necessary to underline 张,because here,老师represents a wide range(there are many many teachers yes?), 张 is a limitation of 老师, it means  not other teacher, but 张老师. (Become refer in particular )

There are many similar circumstance in Chinese words and vocabulary. Like your example,中国画, 中国is the scope limitation of 画，not other country's 画,but here you only want to point 中国的画.
In 'Chinese language' chapter vocabulary , in this similar context ,老师，画，and the rest of your example 剧（we can also use it to create word like 京剧，豫剧，昆剧，平剧 and so on);
语(汉语，英语 …)；
餐（中餐，美餐，快餐…);
文(英文，中文，俄文…)
老师，画，剧，语，餐，文，can be seen a affix, the underlining work you want to do is necessary when you would like to point something in concrete.
 Wish to help u.   :)